# Archive all the text files in a folder in a google cloud bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to copy all the text files in a folder in a google cloud bucket to a folder (named 'archive') within the same cloud bucket. I want this function to be executed at a particular time and copy all the files to the 'archive' folder.

This is how I went on to create this cloud function:

**Trigger:** HTTP
**Requires HTTPS:** 'checked'

**requirements.txt**

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-storage
```

```
main.py
from google.cloud import storage
def copy_daily_trans_file(request):
    """
    Copies the files from a specified bucket into the selected one.
    """

    # Check if the bucket's name was specified in the request
    if request.args.get('bucket'):
        bucket_name = request.args.get('bucket')
        print (bucket_name)
    else:
        return "The bucket name was not provided. Please try again."

    try:
        # Initiate Cloud Storage client
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        # Define the origin bucket
        origin = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        #origin = 'gs://my-bucket/incr-exports/'
        print (origin)
        # Define the destination bucket
        destination = storage_client.bucket('gs://my-bucket/incr-exports/archive/')

        # Get the list of the blobs located inside the bucket which files you want to copy
        blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucketName)

        for blob in blobs:
            print (blob)
            origin.copy_blob(blob, destination)            
        
        origin.delete()
        return "Done!"

    except:
        return "Failed!"
```

Execution command:
[https://us-central1-data-prod-datalake.cloudfunctions.net/func-archive-exports/?bucket='gs://my-bucket/incr-exports/'](https://us-central1-data-prod-datalake.cloudfunctions.net/func-archive-exports/?bucket=%27gs://my-bucket/incr-exports/%27)

I am trying to execute this command in the cloud shell editor.

Can someone help me with the correct way of doing this.

Comment: You are creating a recursive copy. Your code should exclude the destination folder.

Comment: I didn't understand this. How is this recursive ?